# ASP.net button onclick send querystring

Tags: asp.net, button, postback

I have the button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidateNewMessage();" OnClick="PostComment" ID="AddCommentButton" CssClass="nice-button" Text="Add Your Comment" />
```

It is on the URL:

```
blog/42/gregre-re-greg-er-g/comments-6#comments
```

When I click the button, it takes me to:

```
blog/42/gregre-re-greg-er-g/comments-6?ID=42&comments=1&page=6
```

This is making my scripts work strangely, I really need the button to just keep it's URL format and not include the querystring data, is this possible easily?  So fater clicking it, the page is still:

```
blog/42/gregre-re-greg-er-g/comments-6#comments
```

The post comment method is as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Post a comment
/// </summary>
public void PostComment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommentResponse CommentResp = CommentCommon.NewComment(NewComment.Text, this.ThisUser.UserID, this.Anchor);

    if (!this.ThisUser.IsLoggedIn)
        CommentResp.Status = CommentError.NotLoggedIn;

    // Error messages
    if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.CommentsPostedTooQuick)
    {
        DiscussError.Visible = true;
        DiscussErrorMessage.Text = "You are posting comments too quickly";
    }
    else if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.ExceededCommentsPer3Mins)
    {
        DiscussError.Visible = true;
        DiscussErrorMessage.Text = " You are posting comments too quickly";
    }
    else if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.NotEnoughChars)
    {
        DiscussError.Visible = true;
        DiscussErrorMessage.Text = "Comment is not long enough";
    }
    else if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.NotLoggedIn)
    {
        DiscussError.Visible = true;
        DiscussErrorMessage.Text = "You are not logged in";
    }
    else if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.UnspecifiedError)
    {
        DiscussError.Visible = true;
        DiscussErrorMessage.Text = "Unspecified error.";
    }

    // Posted ok, redirect to last page
    if (CommentResp.Status == CommentError.Success)
    {
        int TotalComments = CommentCommon.CountComments(this.Anchor);
        int TotalPages = (TotalComments + Settings.CommentsPerPage - 1) / Settings.CommentsPerPage;
        Response.Redirect(this.PageNavURL.Replace("$1", TotalPages.ToString()) + "#comments");
    }

}
```

The problem occurs when the status ISN'T success, when it redirects it works fine.

Comment: What does your form definition look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does the redirect.

```
Response.Redirect(PageNavURL.Replace("$1", TotalPages.ToString()) + "#comments");
```

The URL appears to be based on the `PageNavURL` property. You need to change that property or the code so it results in a different URL.

Comment: This isn't called with the problem pages im having.  When status == success it works fine.  When status doesn't equal sucess, it skews the page URL.  That's the problem, not that redirect line.

Comment: That's not what your original question said. And that's not what your code says. If there is no redirect, then it's simply posting back to the original URL. What does `PageNavURL` look like?